# Linux Mint 18 / Update problem/ DNS problem / Run script on startup

Tags: scripting, dns, upgrade, startup

I have Linux Mint 18, and always (with Linux Mint 17 too) have a problem with the connection to some repositories in the update option. The solution that I found is to run this in terminal and it works fine:

```
sudo echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null
```

But, I have to do this **every time** when I reboot or shutdown my PC.

I tried a lot of options from the internet to run this command on startup, but they don't work for me.

Any help?

Comment: Try to create a shell script (name it `whatever.sh`) under `/etc/profile.d` folder. Paste `sudo echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null` there. Reboot. It should work now.

Comment: i do, but don't work for me. I read similar answers before. I create script with text editor and save with sh extension, is this correct? the file dosn't header line to identify type file?

Comment: that's strange. Try to add `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to the first line (yet I doubt it would help).

Comment: don't work for me. Thank you so much for help me.

Comment: OMG; i can fix this!! 6 months with this problem!! every time run this command omg... I tell you what i do:

Comment: OMG,i can fix this!! 6 months with this problem!! every time run this command omg.I tell you what i do: i insert the command in the "rc.local" file, changing the commando to: (sleep 60 
echo "my_root_password" | sudo -S echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null) &  I add the password parameter because the "sudo" command, and add the sleep command, because without sleep don't work. I think that is because script was replace for network configuration generated after script run. With sleep, the script run after network system configuration is set. (sorry for my english)

Comment: What kind of internet connection do you use?  (ethernet, wifi, mobile broadband etc.). `/etc/resolv.conf` is updated whenever you reconnect, so the thing to change is one of the config files associated with your internet connection.

Comment: wifi connections. With Linux Mint 17, i have the same problem (now i have the Linux Mint 18). I think that is a linux mint bug.

Comment: @LinuxMintNewbieUser I glad you solved the issue. If you find an appropriate solution - feel free to add it as an answer to your question in order to help others who would have the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you need the file never to be changed then you need to do this:

```
chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

that means:

## man chattr

```
chattr - change file attributes on a Linux file system
A file with the 'i' attribute cannot be modified:
```

Comment: i add: nameserver 8.8.8.8 to end of file of /etc/resolv.conf, and then do your step: https://s31.postimg.org/50xzd58vf/root_alejandro_PC_home_alejandro_002.png

Comment: This works, however is not the best solution. The best solution is to ignore the DNS servers in the DHCP client. Some file systems do not support the +i attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple and easy way, you can simply edit the "**/ etc / network / interfaces**" file, since it defines the file configuration "**/ etc / resolv.conf**" and defines the settings for the DNS Servers, as in this example :

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback

dns-nameserver   8.8.8.8 
dns-nameserver   189.40.198.80
dns-nameserver   189.40.198.81
```

Of course here you will use the dns-nameserver you want and save the file, this will set the dns-nameservers to the local network of your machine automatically so you do not have to worry about resetting them again, and when you need to change the configuration just modify it again in the file "**/ etc / network / interfaces**". ok!